# LIKE not working

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to do just a very simple search function but somehow I cant get it to work. This is my HTML:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
         <input placeholder="Search by name..." type="text" name="field" class="form-control" required="">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 text-right">
         <input type="submit" name="search" value="Search" class="btn btn-univ">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
         <a href="allaccounts.php" class="btn btn-default text-left">Clear Search</a>
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

And my PHP and MySQL code:

```
if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
        $field = $_POST['field'];
        $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM pastor WHERE fname OR lname LIKE '%$field%'") or die (mysqli_error($con));
        // I just added this var_dump to check my input. Input is fine.
        var_dump($field);
        if (mysqli_num_rows($query) < 1) {
            echo "<br><center>There are no pastors with this name</center><br>";
        } else {
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
                echo "
                    <tr>
                        <td>$row[fname] $row[lname]</td>
                        <td>$row[location]</td>
                        <td>$row[phone]</td>
                        <td>$row[email]</td>
                        <td class='text-center'>$row[district]</td>";
                        // check status
                        if ($row['activated'] == 1) {
                            echo "<td><center style='color: green; font-weight: bold;'>Activated</center></td>";
                        } else if ($row['activated'] == 2) {
                            echo "<td><center style='color: #000240; font-weight: bold;'>Pending with Confirmed Phone<em></em></center></td>";
                        } else if ($row['activated'] == 3) {
                            echo "<td><center style='color: #00037F; font-weight: purple;'>Pending with Unconfirmed Phone</center></td>";
                        } else if ($row['activated'] == 4) {
                            echo "<td><center style='color: #0006E5; font-weight: purple;'>Pending (Account Recently Unblocked)</center></td>";
                        } else if ($row['activated'] == 0 && $row['blocked'] == 1) {
                            echo "<td><center style='color: red; font-weight: bold;'>Blocked</center></td>";
                        }
                echo "
                        <td class='text-center'><a href='allaccounts.php?activateid=$row[id]' data-toggle='tooltip' title='Activate Account'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign'></span></a></td>
                        <td class='text-center'><a href='allaccounts.php?deactivateid=$row[id]' data-toggle='tooltip' title='Deactivate Account'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign'></span></a></td>
                        <td class='text-center'><a href='allaccounts.php?blockid=$row[id]' data-toggle='tooltip' title='Block Account'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign'></span></a></td>
                        <td class='text-center'><a href='allaccounts.php?deleteid=$row[id]' data-toggle='tooltip' title='Delete Account'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-fire'></span></a></td>
                    </tr>
                ";
            }
        }
    }
```

I checked my input via `var_dump`, the string I'm searching for is exactly what I'm inputting. In case you need it, The data type on my `fname` and `lname` fields are variable.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Answer (score 5):

You can't use `OR` to combine the fields being searched, you have to have separate conditions for each field and combine those with `OR`

```
WHERE fname LIKE '%$search%' OR lname LIKE '%$search%'
```

Your condition is being parsed as:

```
WHERE fname OR (lname LIKE '%$search%')
```

Since `fname` is true unless it's empty, this condition is practically always true.

BTW, you should learn to use prepared queries to protect against SQL injection.

Answer (score 1):

Change your sql query:

```
SELECT * FROM pastor WHERE fname LIKE '%$field%' OR lname LIKE '%$field%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need change your query for the first contidon

```
SELECT * FROM pastor WHERE fname LIKE '%field%' OR lname LIKE '%$field%
```